# how to save deep learning model and test it after training?

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow, cnn

I have a CNN model written using tensorflow for python, the model is for classifying lung CT images (cancer/no-cancer), after training the model with training and validation data and get a reasonable accuracy, after all, that I need to test the model with test data, but I don't know how to do that? how to save the model and using it for testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the details in this tutorial: [Save CNN model](https://cv-tricks.com/tensorflow-tutorial/save-restore-tensorflow-models-quick-complete-tutorial/)

To summarize:

Tensorflow variables are only alive inside a session. So, you have to save the model inside a session by calling save method on saver object.

```
import tensorflow as tf
saver = tf.train.Saver()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
saver.save(sess, 'my_test_model')
```

For saving the model after 1000 iterations, call save by passing the step count:

```
saver.save(sess, 'my_test_model',global_step=1000)
```

To use  pre-trained model for fine-tuning:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:    
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('my-model-1000.meta')
    saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
    print(sess.run('w1:0'))
##Model has been restored. Above statement will print the saved value of w1.
```

To add more operations to the graph by adding more layers and then train it.

```
sess=tf.Session()    
#First let's load meta graph and restore weights
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('my_test_model-1000.meta')
saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))


# Now, let's access and create placeholders variables and
# create feed-dict to feed new data

graph = tf.get_default_graph()
w1 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("w1:0")
w2 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("w2:0")
feed_dict ={w1:13.0,w2:17.0}

#Now, access the op that you want to run. 
op_to_restore = graph.get_tensor_by_name("op_to_restore:0")

#Add more to the current graph
add_on_op = tf.multiply(op_to_restore,2)

print sess.run(add_on_op,feed_dict)
#This will print 120.
```